# Single Page Application versus jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Can someone tell me the difference of using a SPA and a normal jQuery to reload a particular content of the page.
Eg: Let's say, I have a grid. I can use Ajax/Jquery to refresh the grid every 5sec. How is it different from SPA?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  An SPA uses jquery, so asking what the difference is, is like asking what the difference is between css style attributes.

Comment: I wanted to know why the term SPA is used when it still uses Jquery.

Comment: @CsharpGuy you do not need to use jQuery to make your app SPA. And using jQuery in web app does not make it SPA. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Single Page Application, you fetch data from server in asynchronous manner and update the page `without reloading the entire page`. You can change the content of `parts of pag`e or you can update the `complete html` using the data fetched from server. The important thing is you do not reload the page.

To do that, you can use jQuery of course but it is not must. All you have to do is the update the DOM.

You can either use DOM manipulation frameworks such as `jQuery` or new popular `Javascript MVC` frameworks such as [ember.js](http://emberjs.com/) and [angular.js](http://angularjs.org/) which handles most of the DOM manipulation for you.

For your question updating the Grid in Html page via AJAX queries does not mean the web app is SPA.

Comment: Thank you! I have been told to use SPA MVC. I used the SPA template provided by .net. This gives knockout.js by default but, I used the another Jquery library and reload the grid every 5 secs.
Is this still SPA? sorry for repeated questions but, I am working on Jquery and SPA for the first time.

Comment: If someone can elaborate that would be great.
As an eg., I have a grid. I have to display the data from webservice at certain intervals. does it make sense to use SPA in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the below resources to understand more about SPA

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10376050/1015046
2. http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/Techdays-2012-the-Netherlands/2159